# Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC (by convention) not able to construct interfaces in a different project

Tags: c#, interface, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have the structure like so:

- MyWork.BLL
- MyWork.DAL
- MyWork.Interfaces
- MyWork.Models
- MyWork.Web

I have unity by convention setup in MyWork.Web project. It works fine when I leave Service.cs and IService.cs under MyWork.BLL. I'm trying to move IService.cs to MyWork.Interfaces for organization and decoupling. This way when working on the web project, all I have to worry about is coding against interface and add the using statment for MyWork.Interfaces. However, if I attempt to move IService.cs to the interface project, Unity by convention no longer works. Anyone know if this is possible? Do I have to always keep the interface and its implementation under the same project in order for Unity by convention to work properly? Here is my code for Unity by convention:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
            container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default);
    }
```

Here is the error:

The current type, MyWork.Interfaces.IService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

*Update:*

**UnityConfig.cs under App_Start of MyWork.Web**

```
namespace MyWork.Web.App_Start
{
public class UnityConfig
{
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return container.Value;
    }

    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<ICalculatorService, Interfaces.ICalculatorService>(); // added this per suggested answer

        container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the `MyWork.Interfaces` assembly hasn't been loaded yet. Unity's `FromLoadedAssemblies` call simply calls `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` which by definition only returns assemblies that are loaded (not all referenced assemblies!).

There are two options here:

1. Reference a type in the `MyWork.Interfaces` assembly explicitly inside your `RegisterTypes` methods. This ensures the assembly gets loaded.
2. Call `System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` before calling `container.RegisterTypes`. The `GetReferencedAssemblies()` call will load all assemblies that are located in the web applications /bin folder. This will ensure that not only your `Interfaces` project, but all projects are loaded.

Comment: thank you for your help. Option 1 works perfectly for me. However, option 2 returns an error message "This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase." I tried this above the register type and as well as placing it in the global.aspx file.

Comment: My thought on option 1 - I'm currently taking advantage of unity register by convention feature and if I have to explicitly specify it inside the RegisterTypes method... it somewhat defeats the purpose of "register by convention". This is why I mention in the comment above Option 1 works for me but I still want to explore Option 2. I'm hoping you can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move the registration of Unity to a later point in the application startup phase. For instance to Application_Start.

Comment: My UnityConfig class is indeed under the App_Start folder of the Web project. (Just updated my question with the code for App_Start)

Comment: That's not what I meant. You should configure Unity from within the `Application_Start` method in the global asax (or at least.during that time frame).

Comment: I'm using Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC. The files are in App_Start. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507440(v=pandp.30).aspx

Comment: You can move that logic.

Comment: I apologize. This should have worked 2 hrs ago when I tried to place it in the global.aspx. I must have fat finger earlier. Anyway, I started clean again it works like a charm. Thank you for your help and your patience. Up voted your key comment :)

Comment: Splitting the registration into a PreApplicationStartMethod in order to load plugin assemblies and a second initialization phase during application start with `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies` made some disturbing problems go away. Thanks.